# Не срабатывает нажатие IME_ACTION_NONE на клавиатуре

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли заставить срабатывать нажатие по IME_ACTION_NONE для EditText ? Может кто подскажет, почему оно не срабатывает?

```
edit_text.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.act_context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, IME_ACTION_NONE не вызывает срабатывания слушателя. Создайте свой id для обработки события. Положим некоторый id в ресурсы

```
<integer name="ime_action_id">666</integer>
```

Теперь в разметке EditText

```
android:imeActionId="@integer/ime_action_id"
```

и в коде

```
@Override 
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
    if (actionId == getResources.getInteger(R.integer.ime_action_id)) {
        return true
    } else
        return false
    }
```